# Strategies for logging to application logs from library code?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Where I work we use Log4j for web application logging.  The log4j.jar is at the application level, not the container level.  We're using a daily rolling file appender.  Our log4j.properties files define appenders based on the app package name, so only classes in our application's package and below get logged to our app's log file.

In my application, I'm extending our framework with some supporting classes.  These classes are not in the application's package, as they are not exclusive to my application and will eventually be made into a jar library for use with other applications.  Because of this, my logging statements are not picked up by my application's appender, and are thus not logged to my application's log files.

I want to allow the classes in my jar to log to the log file of the application using the classes.  However, if I create an appender in my application's log4j properties file based on my classnames, I suspect that when multiple applications are using my jar, because of the identical class names in the log4j.properties files, only one application log file will receive my jar's logging statements, and that it will receive ALL the logging statements from EVERY application using that jar.  I think this is the case, since we're using a static Logger.getLogger() call to retrieve the logger.

I first want to know if my fears are valid, if this is really what would happen when multiple web applications in the same or different containers are using my jar simultaneously.

I'd also like to know if there are "boundaries" on which this behavior changes.  For example, does this problem exist regardless of whether log4j.jar is a container-level jar or an app-level jar, or if each container is running in a separate JVM?

Lastly, if this IS the case, I'd like to know what strategies I should use to overcome the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

If log4j.jar is only in the web-app then the logs will stay separate so each web-app should have its own log4j.jar and log4j.properties so that all logs stay separate.

Comment: Even if both log4j.properties files are defining identical appenders for the classes used in my library jar?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the preffered pattern for log4j is to use static *Configurator methods, which don't go very well with application containers.

This [article](http://jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-11277) solved this problem for me when i came across it ...